# References and objects in C#

Tags: c#, class, instance

I am currently writing an assignment for school. I have trouble on how I should comment different parts of my application.

I need to read from files, and therefore I use the StreamReader class.

When I write this

```
StreamReader reader;
```

I have trouble defining what I just did. The C# Yellow Book by Rob Miles defines this very similar code

```
Account RobsAccount;
```

> What you actually get when the program obeys that line is the creation of a reference
>   called RobsAccount.

He follows with an analogy to a luggage tag

> You can think of them as a bit like a luggage tag, in that they can be tied to
>   something with a piece of rope. If you have the tag you can then follow the rope to the
>   object it is tied to.

When Rob Miles write this later on

```
RobsAccount = new Account();
```

He describes it as

> (...)creating an instance of the class and then connecting our tag
>   to it.

```
RobsAccount = new Account();
```

is similar to my case, where I simply write

```
reader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default);
```

After reading a couple of different books on C#, I still cannot confidently comment what is called what. They seem to use different names and different analogies.

So my question is:

What would be a suitable comment to this

```
StreamReader reader;
```

And what would be a suitable comment to this

```
reader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default);
```

My programming teacher says that when you write

```
StreamReader reader;
```

You are making a variable of the type *StreamReader* with the name *reader*. This variable is actually a pointer (hence, reference) to an object that is created by writing

```
new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default);
```

Is this the right way to describe it?

Comment: This is a ***very*** broad question.

Comment: The real answer is, it's a self-commenting line of code, you don't need to comment it.  But I don't think your school would like that answer.

Comment: it's not broad, it may be off topic of SO. Op's may try to ask on other stacksites.

Comment: Th first statement is **declaration**. You are declaring a variable (or reference, as Rob Miles calls it) of type `StreamReader`. The second statement is instantiantion and **assignment**; you are creating a new streamreader and assigning it to your `reader` variable. Your teacher's explanation is the right way to describe it.

Comment: I'm surprised he doesn't use camel case for his variable names.

Comment: @jonesy The teacher know that I am a decent coder, and understand all the basic data structures and things like if, else, loops, etc. But some in my class fill up their assignments telling how they used this smart if statement to determine if something was true or not. It's really cute.

Answer (score 3):

```
StreamReader reader;
```

This is variable declaration.

```
reader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default);
```

Here you are instantiating the variable "reader" with the object of StreamReader class.

Comment: I wouldn't say that you "instantiate" a variable.  You instantiate the `StreamReader` type and *assign* it to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between declaring a variable and instantiating a variable in C#.  When you write the line

```
StreamReader reader;
```

You are creating a reference to a null StreamReader object with the name reader.  If you try to use it before instantiating it, you will get a null object reference.  When you make your comment, you can state that you have declared an object reference.

When you write the following line

```
reader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default);
```

You are instantiating the `reader` object.  That is, you are giving a value to the object reference you created earlier.  When you comment on this line, you can say that you have instantiated the object.  After this point you should not receive a NullReference exception if you attempt to reference this object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about internal documentation, then you should comment on the functionality of variables when you declare them (what is it for--why did you make it). 
Here's a link for some quick tips on documentation: [(download)](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~shawg/syl/internal-doc.doc)

If your assignment is to describe what is happening behind the scenes (i.e. to "Play Computer") then

```
StreamReader reader;
```

is a declaration. It means that Java has reserved that name as a reference and it knows that reference will point to a location in memory that has data representing that type ('class').

When you do

```
new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default);
```

You are actually modifying the contents of the container to which the reference points. The 'new' keyword tells Java you want to get some memory and the NewReader() function call modifies that memory while the JVM (virtual machine) maintains the name/reference->container/data relationship.

Comment: Java is not C#... Close enough for school assignments, but you should at least explicitly said so your post...

Answer (score 0):

> When I write this
>
> ```
> StreamReader reader;
> ```
>
> I have trouble defining what I just did. The C#
>   Yellow Book by Rob Miles defines this very similar code
>
> ```
> Account RobsAccount;
> ```

- The only thing similar is that in both cases, a variable is being declared.
- Forget the analogy, although it's correct, it seems to be confusing you more than it's doing any good, if there's something you enjoy doing, hobby etc I can tailor one for you so that you can relate to it...

> When Rob Miles write this later on
>
> ```
> RobsAccount = new Account();
> ```
>
> He describes it as (...)creating an instance of the class and then connecting our tag to it.

So let's break that down...

```
// The code below is instantiating a new object.
// new Account();

// The code below is declaring a variable, at the moment it is null
// This is because it isn't referencing any objects that we've created.
Account RobsAccount;

// The `=` character is an assignment operator, and we'll need it to 
// assign objects that we create to variables.
// The code below will assign an object of type Account, to the variable
// RobsAccount which has a type of Account.
RobsAccount = new Account();

// Now the `RobsAccount` variable is pointing to the object
// that we just instantiated
```

Moving on to your final question...

> What would be a suitable comment to this
>
> ```
> StreamReader reader;
> ```
>
> And what would be a suitable comment to this
>
> ```
> reader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default);
> ```

```
// A declaration of a StreamReader variable.
StreamReader reader;

// Assigning a the `reader` variable with a new StreamReader object 
// that has been instantiated with the following parameters
// - The file path of the document to read
// - The encoding of the file to read
reader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default);
```

---

Keywords:

- Type: Every variable or constant has a `Type`, it might be a `string`, an `integer`, a `boolean`, `StreamReader` or a type that you've defined using a `class` or `struct`, any expression that evaluates to a value has a `Type`.
- Class: A `reference type` references an object. Imagine your class register, it will reference you, there are many registers, but they all reference you as a person.
- Struct: A `value type` that references a value. If your class register was to reference your name by value, and you were to change your name, the register would still be referencing the old value.
- Instantiating: To create an instance of a class.
- Object: Is what you receive as a result of instantiating a class
- Variable: Is an instance of a `type`, if the variable is a `value type`, then it will always consist of a value, if the variable is a `reference type`, then it may also be null, as a `reference type` may not be referencing anything at all, however, a value type will always have default value... (Don't be tricked by `int?` it's a value type! It just translates into `Nullable<int>`, but the `Nullable` type is in fact a `struct`